# How can I use a package written using typescript in a nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a project with legacy node.js, express code. The project does not use typescript. Now, there's a requirement to use a package from npm, which is in typescript.

Is there a way to make that package compatible with the project?

Comment: Just use it. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, of course. Didn't work.

Comment: What is `didn't work` mean?